# convert text file of key value pairs to json

Tags: java, json

I have a text file that has some key value pairs in it, written like this:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

I need to convert these to a json object using java and/or Spring:

```
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3 }
```

what would be the cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json):

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Saar\\IdeaProjects\\so2\\src\\main\\resources\\dd.txt"));

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
lines.forEach(line -> {
    String[] split = line.split(" = ");
    jsonObject.put(split[0], split[1]);
});

System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

Comment: You may want to limit the splitting to produce at most 2 elements. For example, a line *may* contain something like `expression=5+7=12`, which will then split into `expression` and `5+7=12`.